# Is there an easier way to calculate a million formulas in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have about 80 columns that contain formulas in them, which I use to drag down into the sheet using VBA and calculate them, and finally turning them into values using .formula = .value.

The amount of formulas varies but sometimes Excel will have to perform about a million calculations, and it eats up a lot of time. How can I speed this up? I have used arrays and other techniques that don't seem to speed things up.

Comment: Define “a lot of time”? I used to set macros running at 17:00 and expect them complete for 08:00 next morning. But also would set some jobs running that took 30 days but that was CFD…

Comment: "I have used arrays and other techniques" - please provide details both on your formulas, and the other approaches you tried, and how they compared.  We don't want to waste time suggesting avenues you already explored.

Comment: @SolarMike Two minutes for 15k rows over 80 columns

Comment: @TimWilliams Suggest away. I’m not that great at arrays in VBA

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("My_Whole_Range").Value = _
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("My_Whole_Range").Value
```

This will do the job insantly.